# Can $(0,0,0)$ be considered a particular solution in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the following matrix $A$:
$$
\left[    
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 5 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$

If we solve $Ax = 0$, we get the general solution as:
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-5t_1 - 2t_2\\
t_1\\
t_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Is $(0,0,0)$ a particular solution or does a particular solution not exist?

Comment: For any  linear application,$ A(0,0,0,0,0,..0)=\vec{0}$

Comment: Of course $\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}$ is a particular solution; not a very interesting one though. But plenty of others exist; just substitute your favourite numbers for $t_1$ and $t_2$ in your formula.

Comment: It is technically a particular solution, but usually that term is used in the context of a linear system (not necessarily of algebraic equations) $Ax=b$ with $b \neq 0$, because in that case it is useful to write the general solution to such an equation as a decomposition of some particular solution and the general homogeneous solution. In an equation that's already homogeneous, this decomposition doesn't really do anything, because whatever particular solution you select is already inside the general homogeneous solution anyway.

Comment: Typically, the term "particular solution" is only used for an equation of the form $Ax = b$ with $b \neq 0$. In other words, the term "particular solution" is reserved for non-homogeneous problems

Answer (score -1):

In general solutions for a linear system are given by

$$Ax=b \quad x=x_P+x_H$$

such that

$$Ax_P=b \quad Ax_H=0 \implies A(x_P+x_H)= Ax_P+Ax_H=b+0=b$$

In this case $b=0$ therefore the zero vector is a particular solution and some not trivial particular solution are for example

$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
\frac15\\
-\frac12
\end{matrix}
\right],\quad \left[
\begin{matrix}
1\\
0\\
-\frac12
\end{matrix}
\right], \quad \left[
\begin{matrix}
1\\
-\frac15\\
0
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

Comment: I am currently studying from Gilbert Strang's book. He mentions that the general solution =  particular solution + special solution. By that definition, shouldn't (0,0,0) be a particular solution?